# Can Rserve handle a large number of simultaneous requests? Connection pooling?

Tags: java, r, rserve

I am doing a web project, and would like to integrate R with my web application. I am new to Rserve, and I read this article:

http://codophile.com/2015/05/02/how-to-integrate-r-with-java-using-rserve/

and believe that Rserve is a better solution. But I have these questions:

1. Is Rserve able to handle a number of simultaneous requests for statistics calculation? As you know, being able to handle simultaneous requests is a basic requirement for a website, thus for Rserve too, which handles simultaneous requests from a website. If yes, any URL for how-to?
2. As you know, connection pooling is a common technique for heavy traffic websites. Does Rserve support connection pooling? If yes, any URLs for how to?
3. The above article shows that the way to handle multiple requests is to create multiple Rserve instances with different ports. Is this the way Rserve uses to handle simultaneous requests? I have some concerns if the answer is yes. Any URLs for  best practice?

### More information

My systems are all running on Windows, and so I hope to have a solution that work in the Windows environment.

Comment: I would strongly recommend reading about [`plumber`](https://www.rplumber.io/). This package allows you to create a REST API for your R functions and has a more straight forward implementation than `Rserve`

Comment: Don't see any arguments. Both plumber and Rserve are good solutions. Rserve for performance, plumber for easier usage.

Comment: Hi Dmitriy, can Plumer work in the Windows environment and support multi-threads? I heard that Rserve does not support multi-thread in the Windows environment. It has to be unix/linus.

Comment: See also new `RestServe` package: https://github.com/dselivanov/RestRserve